# Formatting a Java console table breaking

Tags: java, netbeans, console

I am working on a project which outputs a table of values (month, interest, payment, amount total, etc.). I have the columns with the values printing to the console within NetBeans evenly spaced an functioning properly, but I also have a single print line above that in order to display a header, this is not matching with the rest of the columns. In case that didn't make any sense I have attached the code I am working with.

```
    System.out.println("Month \t\t Start Balance \t Interest \t\t Principal \t Payment \t End Balance");

    while (true) {
        i++;
        compCost = round(compCost);
        System.out.print(i + "\t \t");//month
        System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(compCost) + "  \t ");//original balance
        double interest = (rate / 12) * compCost;
        interest = round(interest);
        System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(interest) + "  \t \t");//interest
        sum = sum + interest;

        compCost = compCost + interest;//add interest
        payment = round(payment);

        if (compCost > payment) {//check if payment is bigger than the cost left
            compCost = compCost - payment;
            double principal = payment - interest;
            principal = round(principal);
            System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(principal) + "\t \t");//principal
            System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(payment) + "\t \t");//payment
        } else {
            System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(compCost - interest) + "\t \t");//principal
            System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(compCost) + "\t \t");//payment
            compCost = 0;
        }
        compCost = round(compCost);
        System.out.print(patternFormatter.format(compCost));

        System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Can you please parse the code down to just the relevant output code?

Comment: Too much code.Trim it down to specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Using [j-text-utils](https://code.google.com/p/j-text-utils/) you may print to console a table like:
[image]

And it as simple as:

```
TextTable tt = new TextTable(columnNames, data);                                                         
tt.printTable();
```

The API also allows sorting and row numbering ...

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are only going to align your text if the column you are printing isn't wider than the console's tab width.  Take this example:

```
public class SO {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] data = new int[][] {
      {1,2,        3, 4},
      {2,4,314159265, 8},
      {4,8,       12,16}};
    for(int[] row : data) {
      for(int col : row) {
        System.out.print(col+"\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
1   2   3   4   
2   4   314159265   8   
4   8   12  16
```

If you are trying to align these values in a text console then you need to calculate the widest element and generate the padding yourself.  There are libraries that make this easier though.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this library http://sourceforge.net/projects/texttablefmt/ (I usually just dump to a TSV format and let a spreadsheet app align things) but it came up as a high result for the Google search "Java text table generator"

Answer (score 0):

```
package MyUtil.sql;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class sqlResults {
    protected String[][] data;
    protected int column_count;
    sqlResults(String[][] data, int column_count) {
        this.data = data;
        this.column_count = column_count;
    }
    
    public String[][] get() {
        return data;
    }
    
    public List<List<String>> getList() {
        List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for(String[] e: data) {
            rows.add(Arrays.asList(e));
        }
        return rows;
    }
    
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }
    
    public int getColCount() {
        return column_count;
    }
    
    public String[] split(String spChar) {
        String[] result = new String[data.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(String[] e:data) {
            String str = "";
            for(String e2:e) {
                if (str == "") str += e2;
                else str += spChar+e2;
            }
            result[i] = str;
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public String getTable() {
        StringBuffer showTable = new StringBuffer();
        int[] maxLen = new int[getColCount()];
        int i = 0;
        for(String e:data[0]) {
            maxLen[i] = getWidth(e);
        }
        int j = 0;
        for(String[] e:data) {
            j = 0;
            for(String e2:e) {
                if(e2 == "" || e2 == null) e2 = "null";
                
                if(getWidth(e2) > maxLen[j])
                    maxLen[j] = getWidth(e2);
                j++;
            }
        }
        i = 0;
        for(String[] e:data) {
            j = 0;
            for(String e2:e) {
                if(e2 == "" || e2 == null) e2 = "null";
                showTable.append(setWidth(e2, maxLen[j])+"  |  ");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
            showTable.append("\n");
        }
        return showTable.toString();
    }
    
    protected int getWidth(String str) {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), true, true);
        int textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(str, frc).getWidth());
        return textwidth;
    }
    
    protected String setWidth(String str, int width) {
        int strWidth = getWidth(str);
        int count = (width-strWidth) / 3 + 2;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        long matches = matcher.results().count();
        count -= matches;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
            str += " ";
        }
        
        return str;
    }
}
```

This is my code to straighten out sql result

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.